# Bringing my genius brain back

Tags: productivity

Well... I was hired because I did not take a comp-sci or engineering course, however I was really good at coding. My job is doing the heterodox stuff when needed... You know, the guy that sometimes has to use a goto, or invent some bizarre technology.

When I started my job, I blasted though stuff I needed to do, then I got slower and slower until I almost got fired.

Now I am more or less stable, but I am noticing I am slowing down again. I plainly open my source code, look at it, and have no idea what I have to do, sometimes I do not know even what I was doing.

I think this is related to my lifestyle. My work is a two hour commute (meaning I lose 4 hours daily), and I have not completed university yet (so I need to do some university work at home), and on weekends I spend time with my significant other.

Does anyone know what to do in a situation like this? I am depressed that I cannot write code like I could when I started, or when someone would throw some oddball problem at me and I would spit out a solution instantly. Now I am having trouble typing even 10 lines of code in a day, because I spend the entire day trying to figure what to do.

In fact, I can't even  procrastinate when I **want** to procrastinate, I open the browser, and I have no idea of what web page to open. It is really annoying :(

I feel like my IQ dropped from its measured levels to something like 80...

Comment: Try to use these 4 hours to do some stuff for university... at least then the time's not wasted...

Comment: 4 hours a day: either look for another job closer to home or ask to work from home for a couple of days a week.

Comment: To topic closers: It cannot be salvaged? (and why it was closed anyway?)

Comment: Do'h. I spent all that time making this English readable and it's closed now.

Comment: @OliverWeiler   I am currently sleeping in the first two hours... And in the second two hours I cannot do anything, because the return trip is quite chaotic (with high-volume TV, people chatting loudly, whatnot...)

Comment: Thanks incognito... Even if they closed it :(   And sorry for the bad english (I am not native english speaker)

Comment: Make sure you get enough sleep, exercise at least once a week, eat at regular hours and do something creative and fun once a week. Try to study or sleep during commute. Try wearing large headphones with noise cancellation.

Comment: Also consider either moving, switching job, or both.

Comment: @Incognito: 3 reopen votes. Almost there.

Comment: Ah, I think I've spotted what the problem is. That pesky SO of yours. It's commonly accepted that you can't have a *life* and be a *great coder* at the same time, so just get rid of the SO and free up all of those precious weekend hours for honing your skills with an open source project or six. If you want real *guru* status though, you'll need to find a few hours for high intensity relaxation, like extreme sports. If you're creative you could combine this with your [commute home every evening](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Train_surfing)...

Comment: @Mark Booth heh, XD Awesome... But naaah, my SO is part of my grand plan hehehehe... (she do lots of stuff for me, only right now she is also muddled with time, but after she free time, she will do lots of stuff for me, and leave me free to code ;)  )

Comment: I want to move, but I cannot now :( Or find a closer job (ie: all jobs are in the same place, that has rents that are more expensive than a Junior-level wage... While less expensive (not cheaper) living places are in the middle of nowhere). And now those nested () made my comment look like LISP.

Comment: Burnout is common among programmers. You may be encountering this. You also could have pushed your knowledge/skill as far as it will go and this might be a contributing factor. Lastly, you could be experiencing depression which will probably require medical attention to solve.

Comment: I wonder how to separate burnout from depression from general exaustion from bad sleep pattern.

Comment: Solution is simple: Live at work and buy lots of tuna. Produce a lot of good code, then switch back to {current-halfBaked-mode-you're-in} for a month, then when boss panics, go back to Tuna-LiveIn mode. Life is tough, but hey - you got a decent job.

Comment: I already buy lots of tuna! =D (I only wonder why you suggested tuna... but, ok :P)

Comment: @speeder - Lack of sleep, specifically lack of REM sleep, can cause depression and can become a chronic condition. It can be addressed by lifestyle modification and, if that doesn't work, appropriate medication. I use melatonin myself to help with this.

Comment: it's called "burnout". take a vacation. work on one thing at at time, or nothing at all. sleep. talk to people. read fiction. sit in the park and do _nothing_ for a half-hour but breathe.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You sound like you're tired really, you're doing a lot of stuff and that 4 hours of travelling is a killer (I do 3 a day so I can feel your pain). I'd recommend getting to sleep earlier, try take some time off work if you have any holidays available and rest and relax.

Comment: Yup, sounds like exhaustion to me. Sleep, exercise and "me time" are usually the antidotes for such a condition.

Comment: Agreed. If you're sleeping less than 7 hours a night this is pretty much guaranteed to be the reason for "slacking".

Comment: I am sleeping 5:30 hours (usually) at my bed and then 1:30 hours at the bus in the morning (ie: I sleep at 00:00, wake up 5:30, board the bus 6:30, sleep, wake up again 8:00, exit the bus). But since many yimes I end sleeping past 0:00 or something else... I think you are right.

Comment: The 5:30 will be whats getting you, I've heard of people successfully doing power naps but get 7+ hours straight and your brain will thank you.

Comment: Hey! You was right :P I got fired from that job... Now I am a genius again, but this time making sure I am sleeping properly, and living a 15 minute walk from office :)

Answer (score 2):

Either lack of motivation or burnout issue (too much coding). Retrospect yourself. Are you happy at your job? Do you really like doing what you are doing right now? Talk to your friends and they may be able to point out what they see wrong with your attitude towards things.

Comment: I love my job... I would prefer to be doing games, not what I am doing now, but I still love it :) My job is basically my dream job (invent stuff, code it, show to boss... invent more stuff, code it, show to boss... repeat as long I find it fun).

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you're in over your head. Here are some things you need to decide:

- Whether your four-hour commute is worth your time or if you should rather be working somewhere closer to home.
- Whether completing your university education is more important than working full-time.
- Whether the type of work you are doing is right for you. You may have simply lost interest in working at your current job, so moving on will be better for you and your current employer.

You basically need to prioritize what is most important for you and let that guide your decision-making process.

Good luck!

Comment: I right now live with my parents again (results of a housing bubble here...), and they told me if I did not took a full-time job at whatever I wanted, I would work as cashier in the supermarket full-time. (and I need money to pay university loans anyway... the debt is in my name, not my parents name, and it is quite big... and they do not have money to pay it either...)

Comment: @speeder, time to take a break from your studies so you can concentrate on earning enough money.  Then when you have the surplus again, then consider continueing your education.

Comment: I wish I could do that, but if I do not finish them right now, I will be banned from university and will have to start over (Brazil has some silly education system)